# Pausing Longer After Pesucha/Setuma

Tags: halacha, torah-reading

Should a Baal Koreh pause longer after a pesucha or chasuma than he would for the end of a posuk for Krias Hatorah?

Comment: Any reason to think he shouldn't? That's how normal people read paragraphed text.

Comment: It doesn't seem like most of the Baalei Kriah I've seen throughout the Tri-State area pause longer than a sof posuk, so I'm curious if the Poskim discuss this.

Comment: Most baalei kriah don't know the difference between a kadma and a pashta....

Comment: I think pesucha etc. is more of a halacha in the writing of the Sefer Torah than the reading of it. You can have a parsha break in middle of a passuk, and I assume one should definitely not pause extra there.

Comment: @N.T. On the contrary I do stop in the middle of a pasuk there. Why would there be a paragraph break if not to indicate a stop?? What you're proposing is surely internally consistent; it just makes no sense.

Comment: @DoubleAA There is a stop because of the esnachta, but I don't think it means to pause *extra*. We also find that Parshas Vayechi has no break in front, and yet we stop. See also Shemos 20:14 where in ta'am tachton there are three breaks in the passuk with two of them only having minor pauses. If you pause after the tipcha for too long, you'll break up the phrase.

Comment: @N.T. I don't understand what you are showing from vayechi as we make Aliya breaks all the time not at parsha breaks. I'm also not convinced pausing after a tipcha breaks up any meaningful phrase there, not to mention your question is on God for putting a break there, not me for reading it. (Also it's Shmos 20:12 https://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0220.htm#12 )